# How to choose the right strategy at runtime when implementing the strategy pattern?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, design-patterns, dependency-injection, ioc-container

### Problem description

Consider the following implementation of the strategy pattern:

```
// this is the strategy definition
public interface ICalculator
{
  int ComputeResult(int a, int b);
}

// this is an implementation of the strategy
public sealed class SumCalculator: ICalculator 
{
  public int ComputeResult(int a, int b) => a + b;
}

// this is another implementation of the strategy
public sealed class SubtractionCalculator: ICalculator 
{
  public int ComputeResult(int a, int b) => a - b;
}
```

Let's suppose we need to write some client code for the `ICalculator` service. The client code is given the following input data:

- an integer number, via the variable `a`
- another integer number, via the variable `b`
- contextual information used to decide which strategy needs to be used. Let's suppose to have an enum named `TaskType` whose possible values are `Sum` and `Subtract`.

From a functional perspective, the client code should do something like this:

```
int a = GetFirstOperand();
int b = GetSecondOperand();
TaskType taskType = GetTaskType();

ICalculator calculator = null;

switch(taskType)
{
  case TaskType.Sum:
    calculator = new SumCalculator();
    break;

  case TaskType.Subtract:
    calculator = new SubtractionCalculator();
    break;    

  default:
    throw new NotSupportedException($"Task type {taskType} is not supported");
}

int result = calculator.ComputeResult(a,b);
Console.Writeline($"The result is: {result}");
```

Consider now a codebase using dependency injection and delegating object creation and lifetime management to a DI container. In this case, the client code of the `ICalculator` service **can't** directly take the responsibility of creating objects.

**What I'm trying to find is, basically, an elegant and effective way to solve this problem.**

### What I usually do in this scenario

This is what I usually do to solve this problem. I call this design pattern the *composite design pattern*, but I'm quite sure this is not exactly the pattern named *composite design pattern* in the [gang of four book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns).

First of all, a reshape of the `ICalculator` interface is needed (more on this later):

```
public interface ICalculator
{
  int ComputeResult(int a, int b, TaskType taskType);
  bool CanHandleTask(TaskType taskType);
}
```

The existing interface implementations need to be changed:

```
public sealed class SumCalculator: ICalculator 
{
  public int ComputeResult(int a, int b, TaskType taskType)
  {
    if (!this.CanHandleTask(taskType))
    {
      throw new InvalidOperationException($"{nameof(SumCalculator)} cannot handle task {taskType}");
    }
    
    return a + b;
  }
  
  public bool CanHandleTask(TaskType taskType) => taskType == TaskType.Sum;
}

public sealed class SubtractionCalculator: ICalculator 
{
  public int ComputeResult(int a, int b, TaskType taskType)
  {
    if (!this.CanHandleTask(taskType))
    {
      throw new InvalidOperationException($"{nameof(SubtractionCalculator)} cannot handle task {taskType}");
    }
    
    return a - b;
  }
  
  public bool CanHandleTask(TaskType taskType) => taskType == TaskType.Subtract;
}
```

A third implementation of the `ICalculator` interface needs to be written. I call this object the composite object:

```
public sealed class CompositeCalculator: ICalculator 
{
  private readonly IEnumerable<ICalculator> _calculators;
  
  public CompositeCalculator(IEnumerable<ICalculator> calculators)
  {
    _calculators = calculators ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(calculators));
  }

  public int ComputeResult(int a, int b, TaskType taskType)
  {
    if (!this.CanHandleTask(taskType))
    {
      throw new InvalidOperationException($"{nameof(CompositeCalculator)} cannot handle task {taskType}");
    }
    
    var handler = _calculators.First(x => x.CanHandleTask(taskType));
    return handler.ComputeResult(a, b, taskType);
  }
  
  public bool CanHandleTask(TaskType taskType) => _calculators.Any(x => x.CanHandleTask(taskType));
}
```

This is the client code of `ICalculator`:

```
// this class encapsulates the client code of ICalculator
public sealed class AnotherService 
{
  private readonly ICalculator _calculator;
  
  public AnotherService(ICalculator calculator)
  {
    _calculator = calculator ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(calculator));
  }
  
  public void DoSomething()
  {
    // code omitted for brevity
    int a = ...;
    int b = ...;
    TaskType taskType = ...;
    
    var result = _calculator.ComputeResult(a, b, taskType);
    Console.Writeline($"The result is {result}");
  }
}
```

Finally, here is the registration of the `ICalculator` interface in the DI container:

```
services.AddSingleton<SumCalculator>();
services.AddSingleton<SubtractionCalculator>();

services.AddSingleton<ICalculator>(sp => 
{
  var calculators = new List<ICalculator>
  {
    sp.GetRequiredService<SumCalculator>(),
    sp.GetRequiredService<SubtractionCalculator>()
  };
  
  return new CompositeCalculator(calculators);
});
```

This pattern works, but I don't like the fact that the `ICalculator` interface needs to be modified in order to introduce the `CanHandleTask` method and the extraneous parameter `taskType` to the `ComputeResult` method.

The original definition of the `ICalculator` interface (see the Problem description above) seems to be **a more natural definition** for a service able to compute a result using two integer numbers as input to the computation.

### An alternative solution

An alternative solution to this problem is introducing a factory object for the `ICalculator` interface. This is somewhat similar to the [`IHttpClientFactory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.ihttpclientfactory?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) interface introduced in .NET core.

This way we can keep the original definition for the `ICalculator` interface:

```
public interface ICalculator
{
  int ComputeResult(int a, int b);
}
```

We need to introduce a factory object for `ICalculator` instances:

```
public interface ICalculatorFactory
{
  ICalculator CreateCalculator(TaskType taskType);
}
```

These are the implementations of the `ICalculator` interface (no more need for the composite object):

```
public sealed class SumCalculator: ICalculator 
{
  public int ComputeResult(int a, int b) => a + b;
}
    
public sealed class SubtractionCalculator: ICalculator 
{
  public int ComputeResult(int a, int b) => a - b;
}
```

This is the new version of the client code:

```
// this class encapsulates the client code of ICalculator
public sealed class AnotherService 
{
  private readonly ICalculatorFactory _calculatorFactory;

  public AnotherService(ICalculatorFactory calculatorFactory)
  {
    _calculatorFactory = calculatorFactory ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(calculatorFactory));
  }

  public void DoSomething()
  {
    // code omitted for brevity
    int a = ...;
    int b = ...;
    TaskType taskType = ...;
    
    var calculator = _calculatorFactory.CreateCalculator(taskType);
    
    var result = calculator.ComputeResult(a, b);
    Console.Writeline($"The result is {result}");
  }
}
```

The concrete implementation for the `ICalculatorFactory` interface delegates the object creation to the DI container and is defined inside the composition root (because it depends on the DI container directly):

```
public sealed class ServiceProviderCalculatorFactory: ICalculatorFactory
{
  private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;
  
  public ServiceProviderCalculatorFactory(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
  {
    _serviceProvider = serviceProvider ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(serviceProvider));
  }
  
  public ICalculator CreateCalculator(TaskType taskType) 
  {
    switch(taskType)
    {
      case TaskType.Sum:
        return _serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<SumCalculator>();
    
      case TaskType.Subtract:
        return _serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<SubtractionCalculator>();
    
      default:
        throw new NotSupportedException($"Task type {taskType} is not supported");
    }
  }
}
```

Finally, here is the service registration on the DI container:

```
services.AddSingleton<SumCalculator>();
services.AddSingleton<SubtractionCalculator>();
services.AddSingleton<ICalculatorFactory, ServiceProviderCalculatorFactory>();
```

The main advantange of this solution is avoiding all of the `CanHandle` ceremony of the composite pattern described above.

### Question

Is there a better or canonical way to resolve this problem ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe a slight variation of the first solution:

```cs
public interface ICalculatorStrategy
{
    int ComputeResult(int a, int b);

    TaskType TaskType { get; }
}

public class SumCalculator : ICalculatorStrategy
{
    public int ComputeResult(int a, int b) => a + b;

    public TaskType TaskType => TaskType.Sum;
}

public sealed class SubtractionCalculator: ICalculatorStrategy 
{
    public int ComputeResult(int a, int b) => a - b;
    
    public TaskType TaskType => TaskType.Subtract;
}

public interface ICalculator
{
    public int ComputeResult(int a, int b, TaskType type);
}

public class Calculator : ICalculator
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<ICalculatorStrategy> _strategies;

    public Calculator(IEnumerable<ICalculatorStrategy> strategies) => 
        _strategies = strategies;

    public int ComputeResult(int a, int b, TaskType type)
    {
        var strategy = _strategies.FirstOrDefault(s => s.TaskType == type)
                       ?? throw new InvalidOperationException($"No strategy found for type {type}");

        return strategy.ComputeResult(a, b);
    }
}
```

MS DI container can inject the `IEnumerable<ICalculatorStrategy>` for you.

```cs
services.AddTransient<ICalculatorStrategy, SumCalculator>();
services.AddTransient<ICalculatorStrategy, SubtractionCalculator>();
services.AddTransient<ICalculator, Calculator>();
```

Answer (score 2):

> Consider now a codebase using dependency injection and delegating object creation and lifetime management to a DI container.

It is possible to inject dependencies through constructor. Let me show an example.

I've little bit changed names.  So now enum will look like this:

```
public enum OperationType
{ 
    Sum, 
    Subtract 
}
```

This is your abstraction:

```
public interface IOperation
{
    int Compute(int a, int b);
}
```

And its concrete implementations:

```
public class SumOperation : IOperation
{
    public int Compute(int a, int b) => a + b;
}


public class SubtractionOperation : IOperation
{
    public int Compute(int a, int b) => a - b;
}
```

And then we inject all dependencies through constructor to allow future clients of `CalculatorOperationFactory` to use concrete implementations of `IOperation` by operation type:

```
public class CalculatorOperationFactory
{
    private Dictionary<OperationType, IOperation> _operationByType;

    public CalculatorOperationFactory(SumOperation sumOperation, 
        SubtractionOperation subtractionOperation)
    {
        _operationByType = new Dictionary<OperationType, IOperation>()
        {
            { OperationType.Sum, sumOperation },
            { OperationType.Subtract, subtractionOperation },
        };
    }

    public IOperation GetInstanceByOperationType(OperationType taskType) 
        => _operationByType[taskType];
}
```

And then you can inject `CalculatorOperationFactory` to `AnotherService`:

```
public class AnotherService
{
    CalculatorOperationFactory _calculatorFactory;
    public AnotherService(CalculatorOperationFactory calculatorFactory)
    {
        _calculatorFactory = calculatorFactory;
    }

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        // code is omitted for brevity
        int a = 0;
        int b = 1;
        OperationType taskType = OperationType.Sum;
        IOperation operation = _calculatorFactory
            .GetInstanceByTaskType(taskType);
        var result = operation.Compute(a, b);        
    }
}
```

And your dependencies will look like this:

```
services.AddSingleton<SumOperation>();
services.AddSingleton<SubtractionOperation>();
services.AddSingleton<CalculatorFactory>();
```

Answer (score 1):

I would argue that second approach is quite qood. Another way you can handle it is by switching to container which supports keyed dependencies like `Autofac` and use it to generate a `Func` factory as in this snippet created [some years ago](https://gist.github.com/gurustron/2fe50ff8a6173b431fae66e211082f1e):

```cs
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterType<ImplOne>()
    .Keyed<IDependency>(MyTypeEnum.TypeOne)
    .SingleInstance();

builder.RegisterType<ImplTwo>()
    .Keyed<IDependency>(MyTypeEnum.TypeTwo)
    .SingleInstance();

builder.Register((c, p) =>
{
    var type = p.TypedAs<MyTypeEnum>();
    var resolve = c.Resolve<IIndex<MyTypeEnum, IDependency>>();
    return resolve[type];
});
var container = builder.Build();
Func<MyTypeEnum, IDependency> factory = container.Resolve<Func<MyTypeEnum, IDependency>>();
var dependency = factory(MyTypeEnum.TypeOne);
```